# What are these laser tripwires for?

Tags: black-mesa

I found these laser tripewires in Black Mesa, right in front of a ground turret (you can see the turret's laser as well):

[image]

What are these for? The turret? I thought they were laser mines, but they don't explode. They can't be damaged. If you walk through them they just beep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they do is activate the turret.  You can see it's laser finder between the two beams there.  Before you trip a wire, the turret is inactive, and won't do anything.  You can use this to your advantage to avoid them when possible, or to locate the turret for destruction.

Note that damaging the turret also activates it, so ensure you hit it hard enough to destroy it quickly.

Comment: Ah, this became apparent later on in the same area. Curiously the first time you see them it's very hard to tell what they do. Usually they show you how stuff works before they kill you with it

Comment: This is Half Life.  It *delights* in killing you with new things.

Comment: @BenBrocka: If memory serves, the original did this almost exactly the same way.

Comment: @MBraedley I don't recall them having separate tripwires, I could have sworn they were always active

Comment: @BenBrocka: I could be mistaken.  I haven't played the original in nearly a decade.